# Filtering with itemgetter and numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calibrating.py", line 160, in <module>
    intrinsic = calibrate2(corners, cb_points, (640,480))
  File "calibrating.py", line 100, in calibrate2
    valid_corners = filter(itemgetter(0), image_corners)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

`image_corners` is a list of numpy arrays, i.e.,

```
[array([[ 261.45239258,  140.88212585],
   [ 301.11242676,  156.306427  ],
   [ 343.38937378,  168.20132446],
   [ 382.79559326,  180.48405457],...
   [ 392.16989136,  338.6171875 ],
   [ 439.97772217,  337.2124939 ]], dtype=float32), ... ]
```

What I want to do is to take the matrices without the `dtype=float32`, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "take the matrices without the dtype=float32"?

Comment: What is a "valid corner"? Is it any point other than `[0,0]`? (What are you trying to eliminate with `filter`?)

Comment: With "take the matrices without the dtype=float32" I mean that I want to take out the second element of the numpy array tupple, in other words, get a "traditional" array.

Comment: Valid corners is the name I gave to the list which contains matrices that I can operate with.

Comment: What is a "traditional" array? Do you mean you want to convert all the NumPy arrays to eg. lists of lists of float?

Comment: Exactly. That's what I mean.

Comment: See [Convert 2d numpy array into list of lists](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9721884/222914)

Answer (score 1):

The *dtype* attribute isn't accessible by *itemgetter*.

Try this filter instead:

```
filter(lambda arr: arr.dtype != float32, image_corners)
```

That will give you all the matricies without `dtype==float32`.

Answer (score 0):

Or with [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[a for a in image_corners if a.dtype is not float32]
```