# Converting list of Arrays to list of Lists?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

After some complex operations, a resultant list is obtained, say list1, which is a list of different arrays.

Following is the **list1**

```
In [] : list1
Out [] : 
       [array([ 10.1]),
        array([ 13.26]),
        array([ 11.0 ,  12.5])]
```

Want to convert this list to simple list of lists and not arrays

Expected **list2**

```
      [ [ 10.1],
        [ 13.26],
        [ 11.0 ,  12.5] ]
```

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting NumPy array into Python List structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966207/converting-numpy-array-into-python-list-structure)

Comment: possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721884/convert-2d-numpy-array-into-list-of-lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721884/convert-2d-numpy-array-into-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use **[`tolist()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html)** in a list comprehension:

```
>>> [l.tolist() for l in list1]
[[0.0], [0.0], [0.0, 0.5], [0.5], [0.5], [0.5, 0.69], [0.69, 0.88], [0.88], [0.88], [0.88], [0.88, 1.0], [1.0, 1.1], [1.1], [1.1], [1.1], [1.1, 1.5], [1.5, 2.0], [2.0], [2.0]]
```

Answer (score 7):

Just call [`ndarray.tolist()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) on each member array.

```
l = [arr.tolist() for arr in l]
```

This should be faster than building a NumPy array on the outer level and then calling `.tolist()`.

Answer (score 3):

How about a simple *list comprehension*:

```
list1 = [list(x) for x in list1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new_list = list(map(list,old_list))
```

You can use the map function like above. You can see the result below:

```
In[12]: new_list = list(map(list,old_list))

In[13]: new_list

Out[13]: 
[[0.0],
 [0.0],
 [0.0, 0.5],
 [0.5],
 [0.5],
 [0.5, 0.68999999999999995],
 [0.68999999999999995, 0.88],
 [0.88],
 [0.88],
 [0.88],
 [0.88, 1.0],
 [1.0, 1.1000000000000001],
 [1.1000000000000001],
 [1.1000000000000001],
 [1.1000000000000001],
 [1.1000000000000001, 1.5],
 [1.5, 2.0],
 [2.0],
 [2.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `tolist()`:

```
import numpy as np
>>> np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]).tolist()
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 1D list, say 2D or more, you can use this to make all entries in just one list, I found it online but don't remember from whom did I take it xD

```
dummy = myList.tolist()
flatten = lambda lst: [lst] if type(lst) is int else reduce(add, [flatten(ele) for ele in lst])
points = flatten(dummy)
```

You will get a list of all points or all entries.

I have tested on this list

```
[[[3599, 532]], [[5005, 493]], [[4359, 2137]]]
```

and here is the output

```
[3599, 532, 5005, 493, 4359, 2137]
```