# Create a 2D List of Random Numbers between Given Range and without Repeating any Number in Python

Tags: numpy, python-3.8, tolist

My code creates an array, shown below:

```
var1 = array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]])
def Ran(var1):
    var1 = np.random.choice(9, size=(3,3), replace=0)
    #print(var1)
    return var1
var1=Ran(var1)
```

with an output:

```
[[4 5 6]
 [3 2 0]
 [8 1 7]]
```

How can I create the same thing in a list?

Comment: Would `var1.tolist()` do what you are looking for?

Comment: This post here might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404344/converting-list-of-arrays-to-list-of-lists