# Python : conversion from numpy.ndarray to list : getting hung

Tags: python, list, jupyter-notebook, numpy-ndarray

I have a list named `word_vector` whose every element is of type 'numpy.ndarray'.

```
print(word_vector)
```

output:

```
[array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.])]
```

I want to convert the type of each element of the list to list. So I wrote this code:

```
word_vector_list = []
for arr in word_vector:
    list_ = arr.tolist()
    word_vector_list.append(list_)
    
print(word_vector_list)
```

The programming is getting hung repeatedly. I'm getting this exception:

```
IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)
```

length of each element(of type array) of the list is:

```
print(len(arr))
```

output:

```
4395
```

Comment: From the above data, the size seems to be just 4 x 4395. Have you tried converting just one nd array from the list and see how long does it take?

Comment: just tried for one element. It didn't get hung, but I've 10k * 4395 data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why your program is hanging. Try using list comprehension like so, it should be better:

```
word_vector_list = [list(x) for x in word_vector]
```

If it still didn't work, try increasing the iopub data rate. To increase the iopub data rate, run this in the terminal:

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Problem persists even after increasing the data rate.

Answer (score 0):

2d np array can be changed to list of lists directly by .tolist function.

Also seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721884/convert-2d-numpy-array-into-list-of-lists)

Thanks